# How to make activity indicator view to appear in such way, that it will not overlap controls?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactivityindicatorview

That it will appear above some control, but that control will be touchable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` on the `UIActivityIndicator` it should pass events up through the responder chain.